# How to find convolving for the 4 neighbour laplacian;is any mistake in this programe?

Tags: c++, image-processing, convolution

I am trying to implement 4 nieghbour laplacian for Image Convolution:
I am at very basic stage at the movement and trying to build up my concept about 
how to process image. my question is very basic but I am confused.

4 neighbour Laplacian:

0 -1 0
-1 4 -1
 0 -1 0
could any one find error becasue when I run this problem it does nothing and at the last

give me values like below. and image remain same .

(507,503) [r = 55  | g = 55 | b = 55]

(507,504) [r = 59  | g = 59 | b = 59]

(507,505) [r = 4e  | g = 4e | b = 4e]

(507,506) [r = 45  | g = 45 | b = 45]

(507,507) [r = 4  | g = 4 | b = 4]

(507,508) [r = 0  | g = 0 | b = 0]

(507,509) [r = 0  | g = 0 | b = 0]

(507,510) [r = 0  | g = 0 | b = 0]

(507,511) [r = 0  | g = 0 | b = 0]

(508,0) [r = 0  | g = 0 | b = 0]

(508,1) [r = 0  | g = 0 | b = 0]

(508,2) [r = 0  | g = 0 | b = 0]

(508,3) [r = 0  | g = 0 | b = 0]

(508,4) [r = 0  | g = 0 | b = 0]

```
void MyFrame::OnTestingImage(wxCommandEvent & event)
{
    printf("Testing...");

    free(loadedImage);

    loadedImage = new   wxImage(bitmap.ConvertToImage());

    float kernel[3][3]= {{0, -1, 0},{-1,4, -1},{0, -1, 0}};
    int r,g,b;
    float intensity;
    float sum = 0;

    for( int i=0;i<imgWidth;i++)
        for(int j=0;j<imgWidth;j++){
            for(int r = -1;r<2;r++)
                for(int t = -1;t<2;t++)
                {
                    if(r+i<0 || r+i>imgWidth || j+t < 0||j+t>imgHeight )
                        intensity = 0;
                    else
                        intensity = loadedImage->(GetRed(i + kernel[r][t], j + kernel[r][t]));

                    sum += intensity *((float)kernel[r][t]);

                }

            sum = (int)intensity;

            r = g = b = sum;

            printf("(%d,%d) [r = %x  | g = %x | b = %x] \n",i,j,r,g,b);

            loadedImage->SetRGB(i,j,r,g,b);
        }

    printf(" Finished Testing.\n");

    Refresh();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be

```
intensity = loadedImage->(GetRed(i + r, j + t));
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your code right, you're updating the same image that you're reading from, `loadedImage`. So, the sum at coordinate `i/j` will contain the unprocessed values of `i+1/j` and `i/j+1`, but the updated values of `i-1/j` and `i/j-1`. Is that correct? That's not how convolution works: All pixels in the sum are supposed to be the original values. The simplest way to achieve that is to write the result to a separate image.

ADD: And @lennon310 is right, of course, it should be `loadedImage->(GetRed(i + r, j + t));`

Comment: now the first problem is solved becasue r,g,b values are correctly appear but  when whole process finished image get disapprear.sum = 0
(511,503) [r = 1f7  | g = 1f7 | b = 1f7] 
(511,504) [r = 16a  | g = 16a | b = 16a] 
(511,505) [r = 2f5  | g = 2f5 | b = 2f5] 
(511,506) [r = 199  | g = 199 | b = 199] 
(511,507) [r = 276  | g = 276 | b = 276] 
(511,508) [r = 1c6  | g = 1c6 | b = 1c6] 
(511,509) [r = 1c0  | g = 1c0 | b = 1c0] 
(511,510) [r = 1b5  | g = 1b5 | b = 1b5] 
(511,511) [r = 73  | g = 73 | b = 73] 
 Finished Testing.

Answer (score 0):

Its faster if you handle border elements separately, since you can avoid the if statement. Just iterate from 1 to size - 1 and then zero border elements.

you are not accessing right elements. Instead of 
`intensity = loadedImage->(GetRed(i + kernel[r][t], j + kernel[r][t]));`

write
`intensity = loadedImage->(GetRed(i + r, j + t));`

Since you are accessing just five elements you could avoid inner for loops altogether and just write

```
sum = 0
sum += loadedImage->(GetRed(i + 1, j + 1));
sum += loadedImage->(GetRed(i + 1, j - 1));
sum += loadedImage->(GetRed(i - 1, j + 1));
sum += loadedImage->(GetRed(i - 1, j - 1));
sum += 4 * loadedImage->(GetRed(i, j));`
```